# Package SharePoint.Client.Runtime 15.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget-package, sharepoint-online

I am trying to use C# in Visual Studio to write to a SharePoint List . So I tried to install the Nuget Package called SharePoint.Client.Runtime

I am getting the error message below.

```
 Severity    Code    Description    Project    File    Line    Suppression State
 Error    NU1202    Package SharePoint.Client.Runtime 15.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Package SharePoint.Client.Runtime 15.0.0 supports: microsoftsharepointclientruntime (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime,Version=v0.0)
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 4):

The package `SharePoint.Client.Runtime 15.0.0` is quite old and it will not work in a project that targets .`NET Core 3.1`.

You should use the nuget package `Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM` for .`NET Core` application.

Examples how to use `Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM` can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code).